# Looping through a set of webelements using selenium in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I am very new to coding. We are using selenium tool writing scripts in python.

I have the following code for a single web element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("locator")
           height = element.get_attribute('height')
           print height
```

Now I have my xpath expression that is returning 8 items for which I have to print the "height" attribute. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find_elements_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector):

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("locator"):
   height = element.get_attribute('height')
   print height
```

or, [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) if you have an `xpath` expression.

Comment: Hi Alec, Can you please look at and let me know if you can help please....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742148/system-is-unable-to-find-the-element-for-the-second-time?noredirect=1#comment42077930_26742148